# How to keep an image centered and responsive?

Tags: css, position, responsive-design

I have an image, centered both, horizontally and vertically

```
#logo01{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-146px;  // half of height
    margin-left:-229px;  // half of width
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Now I need a responsive design, so:

```
#logo01{
    max-width:45%;
    max-height:45%;
}
```

It works, but position is lost. How can I keep the image centered and responsive at the same time ?

Comment: Try using margin-left: auto;

Comment: @Tdelang `auto` margin doesn't work with vertical alignment or absolute positioning so how is that going to help him?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a dirty way around:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hAe7w/1/)

```
<div class="shadow"><img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" /></div>
```

```css
div.shadow {
    position:absolute;
    max-width:45%;
    max-height:45%;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    overflow:visible;
}
img.logo {
    position:relative;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin-top:-50%;
    margin-left:-50%;
}
```

The trick is to use `div.shadow` as a "dimension holder", so percentage can work.

I call it dirty because the shadow div still possess some space, which will prevent mouse from pointing things underneath it. You can use [pointer event](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) to get around that, but then IE will be left behind, and the image itself would not be pointerble either.

Comment: Great solution! However, on mobile, the image gets sooo smaller... while there is loads of space around it. How can it be changed to show 100% (or near that) on mobiles? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @BNB Have you tried changing `45%` to a bigger number?

Comment: Yes, I did change many combinations (without knowing exactly what they would do) but I can't have it on mobile without "zooming out" the image to about 50% of its size on the screen. On desktops the code is perfect.

Answer (score 7):

Below is my suggestion. It works for any `<div>` `<img>` and ...

```
<div class="parent"> 

    <img class="responsive center" src="http://placekitten.com/800/600">

</div>
```

and the css code is:

```
.responsive{
   max-width:100%;
   max-height:100%;
 }

.center{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.parent{
  position: relative;
}
```

just find and test a live demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/veuodbk7/2/

Answer (score 4):

Try with below css for the container for the image.

CSS:

```
width: 100%; text-align: center; margin-top:50%
```

Comment: Akki619, the container is `body`, it's already 100% and `text-align:center`. margin-top 50% doesn't center the image vertically.

Answer (score 4):

Using table display:

**CSS**

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/herbowicz/a5kumqtv/5/

Answer (score 2):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/hAH6u/2/

```
#logo01{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;   
    cursor:pointer;
    max-width:45%;
    max-height:45%;
    display:table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `display:table` and `display:table-cell` property to achieve this.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='logo_container'>
    <h1 id='logo'><img src = 'http://s18.postimg.org/rwpoh1vo9/forbidden.jpg' alt = 'Logo'/></h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#logo_container {
    display:table;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin:0 auto;   
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #333;
}

#logo {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;

}
#logo img {
    max-height:80%;
    max-width:80%;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qe2vG/

You can see that image is aligned central vertically. Also in case of responsive style, just change the `height` and `width` value of `#logo_container`

Comment: kalpesh, you say: in case of responsive style, just change the height and width value of #logo_container. In that case I would rather change the size of logo itself. But I can't. Responsive design excludes fixed width and height. In case I'm wrong, please make your fiddle responsive.

Comment: @SunSky: If you give height and width in percentage for #logo_container, then also it will work. You can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qe2vG/1/. Try re sizing browser and check.

Comment: kalpesh, i tried your new fiddle and resized the window. `logo_container` is not resized. It becomes cutted. and in it is not vertically centered after resizing

Answer (score 1):

This solution might work just fine :

```css
img {
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 90%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

Since most modern browsers support CSS grid now, I used CSS grid. I know this is an old post but for anyone in the future that doesn't know about CSS grid you should look into it, it's very helpful.

Anyway, here's my solution:

Create a div around the image and give it a class name so your HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="center-image">
  <img src=.... >
</div>
```

Then in your CSS add this:

```
.center-image {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
}
```

Your image should be centered (horizontally). If you want it centered vertically too just add:

```
align-items: center;
```

to your div styling like this:

```
.center-image {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```